# Can openssl client be used for checking if the server key size is what is expected?

Tags: linux, openssl

I was wondering if it is possible for openssl to check the server public key size. Currently, I am connecting to the server using:

```
openssl s_client -connect "ip address":"port" -key client.key -cert client.crt -CAfile myCA.crt -verify 10 -verify_return_error
```

This is on the client side.

The server has been set with a weak server key (1024). I was hoping that there is a one-line solution for rejecting the server because of its weak server key.

Comment: You merely have to look at the certificate presented by the server. Is there a reason you have to do this with OpenSSL? You can do it in a browser as well.

Comment: Yes since I only have a shell access to the device

Comment: Also, sorry for checking I understand, what about rejecting as well

Comment: openssl has options like `-ssl3, -tls1, -tls1_1, -tls1_2, -tls1_3, -no_ssl3, -no_tls1, -no_tls1_1, -no_tls1_2, -no_tls1_3, etc.` which are used to allow/reject connections based on the versions of ssl/tls that the server supports.  It would be nice if it had options like these to allow/reject connections based on attributes of the certificate as well, but looking at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_client.html, that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @mti2935 ahh sweet thank you, so I would have to implement feature, :'(

Answer (score 4):

I want to thank @MechMK1 for providing the partial answer, and @schroeder for editing my questions and mti2935 for pointing me in the right direction, I was able to get OpenSSL to reject the server based on the server public key size. This was done through the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <ip_address>:<port> -key Client.key -cert Client.crt -CAfile myCA.crt -verify 10 -verify_return_error -cipher @SECLEVEL=2:ALL
```

Comment: Can you comment on what part(s) did the trick?

Comment: OP, I think you're on the right track with this, but I am skeptical that using the `-cipher` option with `openssl s_client` in this way is doing what you want as far as rejecting server certificates with RSA public keys <=1024 bits in length.  The `-cipher` option allows/rejects connections based on the cipher (e.g. tls_aes_128_gcm_sha256, etc.) used.  The cipher is only loosely related (at best) to the public key in the certificate.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129987/can-a-ssl-certificate-dictate-protocol for more info.

Comment: To answer both schroeder and @mti2935 Yes mti2935 you are right on cipher suite being loosely connected but, the "-cipher @SECLEVEL=2:ALL" did do it for me schroeder, for mti2935 the SECLEVEL seems to be connected to what public keys size can be accepted as per this document https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html#:~:text=This%20retains%20compatibility%20with%20previous%20versions%20of%20OpenSSL.&text=The%20security%20level%20corresponds%20to,than%20160%20bits%20are%20prohibited. section DEFAULT CALLBACK BEHAVIOUR

Comment: The other arg which seems to work is "-auth_level 2"

Comment: That's really cool!

Comment: SECLEVEL=2 does reject RSA/DSA<2048 (and EC<224, which practically never occurs) but it also rejects SHA1 signatures and DHE<2048 even with RSA>=2048, which are good things to reject but not what you asked for

Answer (score 3):

## How to find the server's public key size

In order to check the size of the certificate's public key, you can use the `openssl` command-line tool. The commands were taken from [this answer by Ari Maniatis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886248/501011) on StackOverflow, so I would recommend upvoting his answer if it was helpful.

Essentially, there are two ways of doing it: With SNI, and without SNI. Some servers require SNI, while others don't support it.

With SNI, the command is as follows:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.example.com -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

And without SNI, the command is as follows:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

You can also use this one-liner to print the certificate information and look for the public key:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text -noout
```

This will print the following output:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            02:52:16:e1:c4:99:8e:26:32:aa:5d:1d:a9:85:b4:3c
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 10 00:00:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Dec  9 23:59:59 2022 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = Los Angeles, O = "Verizon Digital Media Services, Inc.", CN = www.example.org
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
===>            RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a0:30:42:56:d7:0b:a1:11:b9:f3:0b:ec:cc:f2:
                    4c:b0:6f:13:02:6b:cf:07:f3:85:f0:42:8f:c5:54:
                    98:81:6e:7a:93:38:b6:fa:46:42:b3:5c:e6:c9:3b:
                    59:93:61:24:43:20:f5:7a:89:c9:77:ad:ff:87:c8:
                    08:db:86:f5:dc:61:75:96:5f:dc:f0:08:ca:3a:b9:
                    5e:0f:fa:37:7c:65:6a:ca:08:27:1e:9d:d8:0a:3f:
                    9e:10:db:45:25:9a:03:72:ba:f5:27:d9:b0:eb:36:
                    d4:93:39:8c:11:6c:5f:33:14:58:e5:c0:88:c5:1f:
                    7a:21:14:cc:d2:a7:5f:1c:73:1f:d9:03:20:6e:7a:
                    08:ef:17:4e:e3:be:28:c0:4f:e0:71:63:21:04:77:
                    8f:8f:4b:2b:e8:0b:a2:be:97:7e:50:6f:b8:3b:37:
                    63:7f:a4:0c:99:ff:96:a2:c3:7f:ca:7c:21:ba:fd:
                    90:d1:3f:05:a4:34:70:d6:84:8e:a5:00:dc:29:7c:
                    fd:96:cb:43:ae:39:8f:2d:c6:ad:d8:c2:1d:9b:e4:
                    5f:9c:51:9c:8b:fe:6d:49:62:5b:c7:cd:1e:18:96:
                    ce:c6:2a:07:b7:71:80:60:72:ac:57:12:00:90:43:
                    0f:23:be:a9:70:71:d6:e5:7b:85:a3:4d:05:88:21:
                    c7:23
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
[...]
```

As you can see, [example.com](https://example.com) uses an 2048 bit RSA public key. You can also add `| grep -B 1 "Public-Key"` to just display the public key length and the key type. This is necessary, as EC Certificates have significantly shorter public key lengths, yet are considered just as secure.

---

## How to reject weak public keys

Browsers will do that automatically. It seems Chrome and others automatically mark certificates with 1024 bit RSA keys as "insecure" and display a warning to the user.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but related: You can use the tool [testssl.sh](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh) to test the SSL/TLS configuration of a server. It's way easier to use than naked openssl.

Comment: So, one could grep the output to find and act on the key size?

Comment: Thank you, very much, this does help on the checking side of things but on the rejecting of the server key, I was hoping to use openssl, if not a script which has already been written, since I only have access via shell

Comment: @Sad.coder How are you going to access the server? Via HTTPS or SSH? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @schroeder You're right. I added the grep command to my answer. You can't just grep for the key size alone, because it could be an ECC Certificate. Google, for example, uses a 256 bit ECC certificate.

Comment: @Sad.coder so, it looks like one could write a script, but we can't write that script for you. There is enough in this answer to construct a script.

Comment: I should note that it is a very simple server, so the Openssl probably has some implementation of the HTTP protocol. But would I need to have access of the server? to reject the connection with it

Comment: @schroeder Ya thats alright thank you :)

Comment: As commented on the answer you link, `-servername` is no longer needed for SNI in 1.1.1 up (since 2018). Also, AFAICT Chrome and Firefox only warn about RSA<2048  for certs from public CAs, and all of those were required to expire by 2016 so they wouldn't be accepted anyway.